# Angular $resource recursive query

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the API I'm working on I need to take 2 different lists and I need to take in chunks of 20 items to avoid server timeouts.

What I built actually is this:

```
Items1.query().$promise
.then(function (data) {
  $scope.items1 = data.list;
  return Items2.query().$promise;
})
.then(function (data) {
  $scope.items2 = data.list;
});
```

With this code I'm downloading the entire list of objects.

Both the query return:

```
{
    list: [...],
    next: true,
    limit: 20,
    last: 20
}
```

Basically it is a pagination system.

Both services are like this:

```
App.factory('Items1', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('items1/:item1Id', { storeId: '@id'
        }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

I don't really know how to make recursive function with $resource in order to push those items in chunks of 20.

Comment: seems like you need another resource method and api endpoint that includes a page param in url

Comment: I have everything to do the pagination and it works fine, I just need to cycle the query for each item unless the `next` value is `false`

Comment: well if `query()` only returns 20 you need another method that sets the start point

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean... sorry.

Comment: how does api know what to deliver if you don't set start point?

Comment: The `last` value start always from `0` and I need to update it on every response if the `next` value is `true`.

Comment: suggest you read up on how server side pagination is done. If you call the exact same url, will get back the exact same data. You need a url param to tell server to send different data

Comment: I know very well how the pagination is done server side... What I need is to create a recursive function around the `$resource` query in order to get the first 20 items, when done if `next` is `true` query again updating the `last` value `param` unless the response for `next` is `false` that mean I don't have anymore items to query from the server.
My question is: how can I create a recursive function around the `$resource` considering it is already within a `$promise`... Does it make sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg7so3mz/) to show recursive promises.  Converting it for your example, it would looks something like:

```
function getList(resource, list, last) {
    return resource.query({last: last}).$promise.then(function(data){
        list = list.concat(data.list);
        if (data.next) {
            return getList(resource, list, data.last);
        }
        return list;
    });
}

getList(Items1, [], 0).$promise.then(function(list) {
    $scope.items1 = list;
});
getList(Items2, [], 0).$promise.then(function(list) {
    $scope.items2 = list;
});
```

You would need to modify your angular resources to allow you to pass the `last` parameter in the API call.  I'm assuming that the API, if provided with that parameter, will return the next section starting from it.

Comment: Awesome, it works fine and I've understand how to do that properly. Thanks for your help.